# Converting point vector with many fields to multi-band raster

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, rasterization, multi-band

I have a shapefile of evenly spaced points which I'd like to convert to a raster.

In QGIS, I know I can do this with `Raster > Conversion > Rasterize (Vector to Raster)`.

However, I see the possibility to use only one of the fields as a "burn-in value", while I'd rather keep all my fields (at least the numeric ones). I guess I'd like a multi-band raster where each band corresponds to each (numerical?) field in my shapefile.

Is there a way to do that?

My aim would be to be able to symbolize this raster based on one of the many variables (bands), in a way that I can easily switch to another variable and symbology as I need, without having to create different raster for different variables.